# Overlap Collapse/expand content in frameset

Tags: html, css, frame, expand

How can i overlap the collapsed/expanded content display in the frameset ( i dont want top frame details to be shorten) ? I use a 3 framed frameset(top frame,left frame and right frame), and can't make this thing work (script made for overlap the expanded content in top frameset something like z-index logic). Is it possible to make this change? please give some advice. thanks

### frameset page

```
<html>
<FRAMESET rows="18%,*" frameborder="YES"> 
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
<FRAMESET cols="15%,*" frameborder="YES" >
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
<frameset rows="*" frameborder="YES" border="1" framespacing="1" cols="*">
  <frame src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset>
</html>
```

### frame a page

```
<HTML>

  <HEAD>

    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/home/common/popup/popup.js"></script>
    <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>
  </HEAD>    
  <BODY>
    <form name="mainfrm" method="post">
      <table style="background-color:#DDDDDD" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible >></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
              <br/><a href="Javascript:popupWindow( 'https://www.google.com.my/') ">testing content</a>
              <br/>
              <input type="button" value="readMore">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="15% " align="center">TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="40% " align="left " >TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="45% " >TOP FRAME</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Screenshot of current system layout.
[image]

But when i click on expand link, all the top frame details will be shorten. how to make the expanded details layout overlap the topframe instead? 
[image]

expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*please give some advice*"
>
> - Stop using frames: they are not supported in HTML5.
> - Use tables when you need a table. Do not use tables for layout purposes.
> - Always specify a `docytpe`.
> - Use lower case for the HTML tags (or upper case if you want, but don't mix them)
> - Take this list as a recommendation and not as criticism. I made those mistakes too.

As you mention in the question, this can be fixed with `z-index`. The problem that you are facing can be solved by making both tables have absolute position (aligned to the top-left), and giving the first table a higher `z-index` than the second table:

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/home/common/popup/popup.js"></script>
    <TITLE>headerFrame.jsp</TITLE>
  </HEAD>    
  <BODY>
    <form name="mainfrm" method="post">
      <table style="background-color:#DDDDDD;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible >></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
              <br/><a href="Javascript:popupWindow( 'https://www.google.com.my/') ">testing content</a>
              <br/>
              <input type="button" value="readMore">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="15% " align="center">TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="40% " align="left " >TOP FRAME</td>
          <td width="45% " >TOP FRAME</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you @Alvaro Montoro , thank for the recommandation and the solution !!